# DIVs in a parent div overlapping when resized

Tags: css, html

I'm not really a champ when it comes to CSS, so I was hoping I could get some assistance.

Right now I got one parent div with two child divs. Currently, whenever I resize the browser, the two divs overlap each other. I want the left div to be visible at all times.

It can be viewed in action over here: http://unlimitedbrettworks.com/forums/

**CSS:**

```
#header {
     position: relative;
     height: 140px;
     overflow: hidden;
     background-color: #E1E1E1; }
#logo a {
    overflow: hidden;
    float: right;
    width: 620px !important;
    height: 190px !important;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: url(../images/art/logo.png) no-repeat;
}
#userarea {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 1em; 
    padding: 1.5em 1em 0 1em;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 0.95em;
    width: 38em;
    color: #313131;
    font-family: tahoma, sans-serif;
    line-height: 130%;
}
#userarea a:link, #userarea a:visited {
    color: #333333;
}
#userarea a:hover {
    color: #800000;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Comment: Just a little advise for the next time, always work with an static container. Its a container around your website with a fixed width ( prefer 960 pixels ), so the website is always 960 pixels with how big or small your screen is.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. The thing is, I didn't create this forum style. I'm merely editing stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#header {
     position: relative;
     height: 140px;
     overflow: hidden;
     background-color: #E1E1E1; }
#logo a {
    overflow: hidden;
    float: right;
    width: 620px !important;
    height: 190px !important;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: url(../images/art/logo.png) no-repeat;
}
#userarea {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 1em; 
    padding: 1.5em 1em 0 1em;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 0.95em;
    width: 38em;
    color: #313131;
    font-family: tahoma, sans-serif;
    line-height: 130%;
    height: 122px; /* is value is the height min the padding you use.*/
}
#userarea a:link, #userarea a:visited {
    color: #333333;
}
#userarea a:hover {
    color: #800000;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

That is the first problem. The second is on line 128 in your css file.

```
div#wrapper
{
    margin: 0 auto;
    min-width: 764px;
    max-width: 2300px;
    border: 10px solid #333333;
}
```

Needed to be:

```
div#wrapper
{
    margin: 0 auto;
    min-width: 1024px;
    max-width: 2300px;
    border: 10px solid #333333;
}
```

Comment: Edited the CSS. Right now, the logo completely disappears when I resize the browser.

Comment: Yes, you said "I want the left div to be visible at all times." What you wanna do if there is not enough place for the logo ?

Comment: Posted a solution for your second problem. This will help ;)

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have worded my question a little better. I want the left div visible at all times, yes. But is there a way to automatically resize the logo when resizing the browser?

EDIT: Applied your latest edit. Doesn't quite give the expected result. Thank you very much for assisting me though, this is a big help!

Comment: Ah, fixed it. I just set a width of 300px for #userarea. :)

Answer (score 0):

I went to your site, and played with Chrome's inspector, and found an answer.

Try adding these properties to #userarea:

```
#userarea {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #E1E1E1;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This mis-aligned all the text in the userarea.

Comment: Strange, it works fine for me on Chrome. http://jsfiddle.net/DVpzp/ Just out of curiosity, what browser did you use?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I didn't get your question... in the page you linked the #userarea div is always visible even if you resize the window.

To see the #logo div entirely, remove the 'height ' attribute from the parent div #header and it will go on a new line if the window is not large enough.